# Can IEnumerable.Select() skip an item?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have this function:

```
public IEnumerable<string> EnumPrograms() {
    return dev.AudioSessionManager2.Sessions.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(s => s.GetProcessID != 0)
        .Select(s => {
            try {
                return Process.GetProcessById((int)s.GetProcessID).ProcessName;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException) {
                return null;
            }
        });
}
```

The try..catch is necessary since there may be sessions with a PID that doesn't exist anymore. I'd like to skip them. Is there a way to do this from the `Select` callback or do I need to add a new `Where` condition that skips `null` values?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, `Select` always yields one output element for each input element. There's no alternative to that. You could easily write your own `FilteredSelect` extension method - but it's simpler just to use a `Where` clause.

Alternatively, use `Process.GetProcesses()` to get a snapshot of all processes, and then join that to your sessions collection (or use something similar). That would avoid the ugly catch:

```
var sessionProcessIds = new HashSet<int>(dev.AudioSessionManager2.Sessions
                                            .AsEnumerable()
                                            .Select(x => x.GetProcessId)
                                            .Where(pid => pid != 0));
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
var sessionProcessNames = processes.Where(p => sessionProcessIds.Contains(p.Id))
                                   .Select(p => p.ProcessName);
```

Or:

```
var names = from session in dev.AudioSessionManager2.Sessions.AsEnumerable()
            let pid = session.GetProcessId
            where pid != 0
            join process in Process.GetProcesses() on pid equals process.Id
            select process.ProcessName;
```

Comment: That second suggestion sounds interesting. But the processes with audio sessions is just a small subset of the running processes so I guess it would be somewhat less efficient (not that it matters in this case)?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I don't know how long `Process.GetProcesses()` takes, but at least you'd only be calling it *once* rather than once per session.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I'm pretty sure both `GetProcesses` and `GetProcessByID` are calling `EnumProcesses` under the hood.

Answer (score 6):

Building on John Skeet's post this extension method has saved me countless lines of code. The name fits perfectly **SelectWhere**. The code listing below is an Extension method you can use.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectWhere<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        foreach (TSource item in source)
            if (predicate(item))
                yield return selector(item);
    }
```

Usage:

```
entity.SelectWhere(e => e.FirstName, e => e.Age>25);
```

Answer (score 5):

`Select` in Linq is the equivalent to `Map`, while `Aggregate` is the equivalent to `Reduce`. Map/Select is 1:1 input to output. You want to use `Reduce`/`Aggregate` if there is not a 1:1 relationship.

```
public IEnumerable<string> EnumPrograms() {
    return dev.AudioSessionManager2.Sessions.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(s => s.GetProcessID != 0)
        .Aggregate(new List<string>(), (acc, s) => {
            try {
                var proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)s.GetProcessID).ProcessName;
                acc.Add(proc);
            } catch (ArgumentException) { }
            return acc;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Select` can't do that by itself, you could create a custom extension method for that as @Jon Skeet mentioned.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FilteredSelect<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source
    , Func<TSource, bool> predicate
    , Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield return selector(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And use as

```
elements.FilteredSelect(/* where condition */, /* select values */);
```

Answer (score 2):

As others said `Select` always yields one output element for each input element, but if your case is to filter basing on type then you can use `Enumerable.OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable)` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0

For example this:

```cs
var agents = data.Where(d => d is Agent).Select(d => d as Agent);
```

is equivalent to this:

```cs
var agents = data.OfType<Agent>();
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is a simpler version of the extension methods by using LINQ:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FilteredSelect<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    return source
        .Where(item => predicate(item))
        .Select(item => selector(item));
}
```